# Django, deployment on google cloud services, app.yaml file

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, deployment, app.yaml

I'm trying to deploy my django project on google cloud services, but it seems i need an app.yaml file. GCS provide an example yaml file, but i dont know if that example will work for my project as it is because i dont know how to fill the file (i have found other examples that look different from the GCS one), i dont know in which folder that file needs to be, and after watching some tutorials, it seems i need other files besides the app.yaml for the deployment.

Its my first project, so i'm a bit lost, if you can help me, i'll be very gratefull.

Comment: If you are just getting started, start with Google Qwiklabs: https://www.qwiklabs.com/

Comment: On which service are you trying to deploy your django app? You might not need the app.yaml file according to the service!

Comment: Google cloud services, app engine